# Redirect from old domain to new domain

Tags: nginx

How is it possible set a redirection on nginx?
The thing that I need to achieve is to redirect an old domain to the new domain that is the server name.
Trying to use rewrite I am getting problems because with it I need to set as server name the old domain and the new one on the rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name old.example.com;
    return 301 http://new.example.org/;
}

server {
    server_name new.example.org;


    location / {
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: Instead to use return I used rewrite on a different configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "proxy_pass  example.newdomain.com:8080" directive in a server block config of the old host name.